# How to open iCloud Settings through app

Tags: ios, swift, settings, icloud

I am trying to open the user's iCloud settings through my iOS App. Currently, I have this:

```
@IBAction func openSettings(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
    }

}
```

However, this opens the *app's*. How can I open the user's *iCloud* settings? Thanks!

Comment: You can't. The app settings is all that is supported.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your help!

Comment: @rmaddy Has been any update on this ?is still not supported? considering CloudKit needs iCloud and iCloud Drive  to be enabled seems a bit  surprising this is not supported

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let settingsCloudKitURL = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=CASTLE")
if let url = settingsCloudKitURL, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: App will rejected by AppStore if u are use "App-Prefs:root=CASTLE"

Comment: "App-Prefs:root=CASTLE" URL is non-public APIs and  is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Comment: Has this now changed as of iOS 13.1, just saw this article: [link](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/)